# search elements in array and remove from it php

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have the array `$days` like this below:

```
$days= array ("Monday 1 April 2013","Tuesday 2 April 2013","Wednesday 3 April");
```

I would search through it to remove every element that starts with Monday and Sunday.

Comment: Try using [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

Comment: What have you tried? We don't do it for you here. Also, you should not store dates as strings; hope you're not doing that and that this is user input of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_grep](http://php.net/preg_grep)() to get the array elements matching a regular expression. To get the elements *not* matching that expression, make the expression a [negative lookahead](http://php.net/regexp.reference.assertions) (`?!`):

```
$days = array ("Monday 1 April 2013", "Tuesday 2 April 2013", "Wednesday 3 April");
$result = preg_grep('/^(?!Monday|Sunday)/', $days);
print_r($result);
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [1] => Tuesday 2 April 2013
    [2] => Wednesday 3 April
)
```

The regular expression `^(?!Monday|Sunday)` means "Find any occurrence of `^` (start of the subject string) that is not followed by either "Monday" or "Sunday".

Comment: thanks a lot...there's a way to resort and delete the empty keys of array after preg_grep?

Comment: @user1197284 Do you mean you want to have a result like `array (0 => 'Tuesday...', 1 => 'Wednesday...')`? You can achieve this with `array_values($result)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$days = array_filter($days, function($el){
    return !(strpos($el, 'Monday') === 0 || strpos($el, 'Sunday') === 0);
});
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MgwQmT)

Comment: I would replace `if (expression) return false; else return true;` by `return !expression`.

Comment: @ax I edited it as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($days);$i++) {
    $words = explode(' ',$days[$i]);
    if($words[0]==='Monday' || $words[0]==='Sunday') unset($days[$i]);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array=array();

$days= array ("Monday 1 April 2013","Tuesday 2 April 2013","Wednesday 3 April");

foreach($days as $key=>$val)
{

$words = explode(' ',$val);
    if($words[0]!='Monday' || $words[0]!='Sunday') 
{

$new_array[]=$val;

}


}    


}
```